# Query multiple tables in PostgreSQL (LEFT or RIGHT and other)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, menu, privilege

I have 3 table in my PostgreSQL database:

```
menu(id_menu,parent_id,name_uri,uri)
type_role(id_role,name_role)
menutyperole(id_menu,id_role)
```

In my table `type_role` I have the following data (administrator and technician), in the table `menu` exist has many link multi-level to access a other sides, and the table `menutyperole` is a connection with the other tables. I need a query to extract the data of `menu` where no technician is assigned (`type_role` table). I don’t know if I need any condition or anything else?

```
SELECT * 
FROM menutyperole 
     INNER JOIN type_role ON menutyperole.id_role = type_role.id_role 
     RIGHT JOIN menu ON  menu.id_menu = menutyperole.id_menu 
WHERE menu.id_parent != 0
```

Comment: I request you to provide sample data for each table and the expected output in the question

Comment: `parent_id` or `id_parent`?

Answer (score 0):

*One way* (of many) to get rows from `menu` that have no `type_role` assigned:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM   menu m
LEFT   JOIN menutyperole mr USING (id_menu)
WHERE  m.id_parent <> 0
AND    mr.id_menu IS NULL;
```

More:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem... was this

`SELECT * FROM menu 
INNER JOIN type_role ON 
type_role.id_role NOT IN(SELECT menutyperole.id_menu FROM menutyperole) 
LEFT JOIN menutyperole ON
menu.id_menu = menutyperole.id_menu 
WHERE 
menu.id_parent != 0 AND 
menutyperole.id_menu IS NULL OR 
menutyperole.id_role != 1`